# How the bind the visibility of More Button of CommandBar with items in Secondary Commands?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am modifying the default style (generic.xaml) of CommandBar. Now, I am stack at more button visibility. I want to make more button visible only if there are some items to show in popup, otherwise not. In default, the visibility is like the code below:

```
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CommandBarTemplateSettings.EffectiveOverflowButtonVisibility}">
```

I have tried the binding several suggestive visibility available like `OverflowButtonVisibility` but that does not work for my case.

Comment: with `OverflowButtonVisibility` set to Auto, everything works fine. But only when no secondary commands are specified in xaml. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: @Alamakanambra would you please tell me how to set it auto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the Visibility as it is. Just make the `HorizontalAlignment="Left"`. I think it will work for your case.